# Heroku Python deployment fails if a folder is called 'email'

Tags: python, email, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I find that having a folder named `email` in my Python Heroku app with an `__init__.py` file leads to the following error:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.11
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
remote:            from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
remote:          File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 37,
remote:        ImportError: No module named parser
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to testbreak.
```

This is easily replicated by creating a new Heroku app, adding a single `requirements.txt` (with e.g. numpy, django, pymongo, or anything else) to let Heroku know this is a Python app, and adding a single folder named `email` with an empty `__init__.py` file. If you push this to heroku the build will fail. Rename the folder to e.g. `mail` and all works fine.

Any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: My guess would be that it clashes with the built-in [`email` package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html) that Heroku or pip uses.

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk, that would make sense. I take it that naming any Python project folders after built-in packages is a bad idea then?

Comment: The best thing way to troubleshoot would be to contact the Heroku support department. Their code is not open source

Comment: @saq7 thanks. I forgot to mention that I did indeed contact them, but they weren't quite sure what the problem was either. They're aware of this thread so perhaps one of their engineers will look into it.